# How to visit the Hindenburg Crash Site?

Tags: history, military, new-jersey

The Hindenburg crashed in an airfield at the Lakehurst Naval Air Station, which you can [now visit](http://www.nlhs.com/take-a-tour.html) on a base in New Jersey. To do so, as it is a military station, you need to register two weeks in advance, "adhere to strict security requirements", and no foreign nationals are allowed.

[Atlas Obscura](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/hindenburg-crash-site) describes the site this way:

> A simple yet powerful memorial marks the site of the crash. A cement outline in the shape of the Hindenburg stretches across the airfield in the spot where the airship crash-landed in flames.
>   The site was declared a Registered National Historic Landmark in 1961.

I want to know what are the steps to register for a visit?

Comment: There is really no way to answer it.  It may be worth it to you but not so for me.  On top of this how do you judge difficulty?  Lengthy Process? A lot of Paperwork? Possible face to face appointment?  You are planning a visit to the US military installation, so how it is generally not meant to be an easy process.

Comment: To alleviate Karlson's concerns, just ask what the process for registering involves.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the foreign national restriction?  Perhaps a link to the official regulation or whatever it is?

Comment: @phoog The "now visit" link goes to a page from the group running the tours with a list of restrictions.

Comment: @cpast I see, thanks.  I'm more interested in the official wording, since I wonder whether a dual citizen would be allowed.  Such a person is both a US national and a foreign national.

Comment: @phoog Yes.  Since you are a US national and "supposedly" gave up your allegiance to the other country when naturalized.  If you went that route.

Comment: @Karlson I was born in the US of a Dutch father; I was never naturalized anywhere.

Comment: @phoog So you're a US national by birth.

Comment: @Karlson yes, but if the restriction is truly "persons who are nationals of a country other than the US may not enter," as stated on the web site, then I cannot enter.  If it is "only US nationals may enter" then I can.

Comment: @phoog Well.  It's up to you to advertise that you also a foreign citizen.

Comment: @pnuts if I were asked under oath whether I was a citizen of a foreign country (in a US court), and I said "no," I expect that I would be exposing myself to the possibility of a perjury prosecution.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually been to the Hindenburg Crash Site, but until somebody who has comes along, here's an overview on what information can be found online:

As the [website of the Navy Lakehurst Historical Society](http://www.nlhs.com/take-a-tour.html) you linked to mentions, you need to call or email them at least two weeks in advance:

> 1. Everyone wishing to take the tour must adhere to strict security requirements and must pre-register by calling 732-818-7520 or contacting navlake@prodigy.net
> 2. Due to Department of Defense Security Regulations, we regret no foreign nationals may go on the tours.
> 3. All guests must be registered 2 weeks before the date of their tour.
> 4. No walk-ins or additions to the group will be accepted on the day of the tour!

This seems to be confirmed by other sources. For instance this [tripadvisor review](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowUserReviews-g46549-d4509281-r210349237-Navy_Lakehurst_Heritage_Center_Private_Tours-Lakehurst_New_Jersey.html) of a visitor notes:

> You'll need to submit your party members' information, including driver's license numbers, two weeks in advance so that background checks can be performed. This is an active base.

This is also confirmed by two [other](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowUserReviews-g46549-d4509281-r270356696-Navy_Lakehurst_Heritage_Center_Private_Tours-Lakehurst_New_Jersey.html#REVIEWS) [reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowUserReviews-g46549-d4509281-r179285278-Navy_Lakehurst_Heritage_Center_Private_Tours-Lakehurst_New_Jersey.html#REVIEWS). As none of them mention anything extraordinary, I expect they will inform you about what information to send them for the screening when you call or email them.